# Numpy.Matmul and Numpy.Dot: Accelerating code by using Numpy in-built functions

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to speed up a function within my code.

The initial function I had written was:

```
def f(self):
    temp = 0
    for i in range(self.N):
        for j in range(self.N):
            a = self.Asolution[:, j]
            b = self.Bsolution[:, i]
            c = self.Matrix[j][i]

            d = c*np.multiply(a, b)
            temp += simps(d, self.time)
    return temp
```

where `self.Asolution = odeint(...)` , and same for `self.Bsolution`.

`self.Matrix` is a square matrix of size `self.N x self.N` and `simps` is Simpson integration.  `self.Asolution` and `self.Bsolution` have dimensions (t x N).

However, I need to call this function many times, and it takes too long as `self.N` is quite large. Thefore, I decided to give a go to numpy in-built functions as I am mostly dealing with matrix multiplication. I tend to use for loops for everything, which is not the smartest option... Thus, I am a bit unfamiliar with in-built numpy functions. I modified the function to:

```
def f(self):
   d = np.dot(np.dot(self.Asolution, self.Matrix), self.Bsolution.transpose())
   d = np.array(d)
   temp = simps(d, self.time)
   temp = sum(temp)
 
   return temp
```

This is significantly faster, but I am not getting the same result as above.

I think I have misunderstood the use of np.dot or I am missing the way I am multiplying the matrices.
My main goal is to remove the double for loop from the first code, because it takes forever. What am I missing here? Thanks in advance for any hints!

EDIT:

`self.Asolution`  and  `self.Bsolution` have sizes (t x N) - each column is a different position and the rows indicate how the position evolves in time.

`self.Matrix` has size (N x N).

Comment: What have you done to debug this?  Have you compared the `d` values (before the `simps` call)?

Comment: I have not compared the d values because I thought they are two different things (I might be wrong): in the first option I am integrating over each i and j, and them summing the integrals, while in the second option I belive I am summing over the indices first and then integrating. @hpaulj

Comment: The fact that you have a useless `d = np.array(d)` line tells me you didn't test this code in any detail!

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your input, I have now a confirmation that I can remove that piece of code. I am not very familiar with numpy arrays but I found that many functions complained when passed lists instead of arrays, so I was doing this for 'security', in case dimensions were being mixed up or I don't know what. I understand your comment, but please don't assume I just posted this without scratching my head a couple of times before posting; still learning :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many trial and error, I managed to find a way to get the same result faster than with the double for loop. I post it just for completeness and to close the question.

```
n = len(self.time)
d = [np.matmul(np.matmul(self.Asolution[:][i], self.Matrix),
     self.Bsolution[:][i].transpose) for i in range(n)]
temp = np.simps(d, self.time)
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets try this-

```py
# self.t x self.N ----> self.N x self.t x 1
# arranging one column in one layer
self.Bsolution = np.swapaxes(np.expand_dims(self.Bsolution, axis=-1), 0, 1)

# self.N x self.t x self.N == N columns of Bsolution multiplied with N columns of Asolution
# multiplying 1 column of B with N columns of A in a layer done for N layers
product = np.multiply(self.Bsolution, self.Asolution)

# self.N x self.N ----> self.N x 1 x self.N 
self.Matrix = np.expand_dims(self.Matrix, axis=1)

# integration need to take place along axis=1 i believe
# multiplying each of N x N columns(4 rows in length) with N x N matrix elements
result = np.sum(simps(np.multiply(self.Matrix, product), self.time))
```

let me know if it works or not

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the help! Unfortunately, it is not working - as a matter of fact, it complains `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (50,255,1) (50,255) `. My `self.Bsolution` is a (t x N) matrix, so I don't understand what your first line means. Could you describe what you have done? Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, I thought all of them were of N x N dimensions. Could you try the updated solution? it is kinda tricky without being able to verify.

Comment: Hi again! Unfortunately it does not work yet, it is still complaining about dimensions. However, I didn't know `np.swapaxes` and `np.expand_dims`, so I will look into these functions closer. Thanks a lot for your help, this has been useful!